# How to make a table and input 100 random generated numbers into it (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I need to create a table with Javascript and input 100 random numbers from 1-100 into it and sort it in size. The table should be 10x10. I have tried to make it so that both of them merge and work together but It seems that something or a couple of things are incorrect and don't work.  **I am supposed to use document.write() or document.writeln(). for output.**

```html
<html lang="EN">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      </head>
      
      <body>
    
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h1></h1>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container-fluid">
    
          <p class="h4">.</p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                "use strict";
            
                 var numbers = [];
                 var i = 0;
                 while (i < 100) {
                     var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                     numbers[i] = r;
                     i++;
                 }
                 numbers.sort();
    
                 numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
                     return a - b;
                 });
    
                 document.write(numbers);
                 
                 var table = " ";
                 var rows = 10;
                 var cols = 10;
                 for (var r= 0; r < rows; r++) {
                     table += "<tr>";
                     for(var c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {
                         table += "<td>" + c + "</td>";
                     }
                     table += "</tr>";
                 }
                 document.write("<table border=1>" + table + "</table>");
                 document.write("<table border=1>" + table + "</table>");
           </script> 
        <div>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Run again</a>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Not very clear whats the issue here from your question. Can you please explain your problem further?

Comment: `table += "<td>" + c + "</td>";` <-- You are not using the random number, you are using the index of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used numbers array in this code

```
    <html lang="EN">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <p class="h4">.</p>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                "use strict";

                function run(){
                    var numbers = [];
                    var i = 0;
                    while (i < 100) {
                        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                        numbers.push(r);
                        i++;
                    }

                    numbers = numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return a - b;
                    });

                    var table = "";
                    var rows = 10;
                    var cols = 10;
                    var currentIndex = 0;
                    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                        table += "<tr>";
                        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                            table += "<td>" + numbers[currentIndex] + "</td>";
                            currentIndex++;
                        }
                        table += "</tr>";
                    }
                    document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = "<table border=1>" + table + "</table>";

                }
                window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run)
            </script>
            <div>
                <div id="result"></div>
                <a href="#" onclick="run()" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Run again</a>
            </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: everything but the run again works. do you have any idea how to make it so that the button works?

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/9eksqLto/

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1></h1>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <p class="h4"></p>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Run again</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="js-table"></div>
</div>
```

```
const numbers = []
const rows = 10;
const cols = 10;
let table = "";
let numberIndex = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1)
}

numbers.sort()
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
})

for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  table += "<tr>";

  for(let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    table += `<td>${ numbers[numberIndex] }</td>`;
    numberIndex++;
  }

  table += "</tr>";
}

document.querySelector('.js-table').innerHTML = `<table border=1>${ table }</table>`;
```

Comment: I can see the table but they are supposed to be 100 random generated numbers not 1-100 in order.

Comment: And i also have to add that I am supped to use document.write() or document.writeln(). for output.

Comment: @maker https://jsfiddle.net/fekzL5h2/ check with write(). They are not 1-100. They are in diapason from 1 to 100 and sorted. Try to refresh the script and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<html lang="EN">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <p class="h4">.</p>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            "use strict";

             var numbers = [];
             var i = 0;
             while (i < 100) {
                 var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                 numbers[i] = r;
                 i++;
             }
             numbers.sort();

             numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
                 return a - b;
             });

             var table = " ";
             var rows = 10;
             var cols = 10;
             for (var r= 0; r < rows; r++) {
                 table += "<tr>";
                 for(var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                     table += "<td>" + numbers[parseInt(r.toString()+c.toString())] + "</td>";
                 }
                 table += "</tr>";
             }
             document.write("<table border=1>" + table + "</table>");
       </script> 
    <div>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Run again</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that's the case, then I'll modify to remove the number and the extra table.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the array you generated. I would just use a while loop to output the rows.

```html
<html lang="EN">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      </head>
      
      <body>
    
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h1></h1>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container-fluid">
    
          <p class="h4">.</p>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                "use strict";
            
                 var numbers = [];
                 var i = 0;
                 while (i < 100) {
                     var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                     numbers[i] = r;
                     i++;
                 }
                 numbers.sort();
    
                 numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
                     return a - b;
                 });
                     
                 var table = "";
                 var cols = 10;
                 var x = 0
                 while(x < numbers.length) {
                    if (x % cols === 0) {
                      table += (x>0 ? "</tr>" : "") + "<tr>"
                    }
                    table += "<td>" + numbers[x] + "</td>"
                    x++
                 }
                 table += "</tr>"
                 document.write("<table border=1>" + table + "</table>");
           </script> 
        <div>
            <a href="" onclick="window.location.reload(); return false" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Run again</a>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Its not supposed to run double the table, when i run your code i can see that it displays two tables with 10x10 each and then I also see numbers on top of the table. So there's two problems with the code, one is that you have two tables and the other are the random numbers at the top above the first table,

Comment: Because you had document.write twice in your code! I just copied what you had.

Comment: ah ops, sorry for that then. But its supposed to be only one table.